# How to store data from an uploaded .dat file?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a file "exmple.dat" with the following data.

```
    1   2018-09-06 16:29:18 1   
    2   2018-09-06 16:36:03 1   
    3   2018-09-06 16:36:11 1   
    4   2018-09-06 16:36:58 1   
    5   2018-09-06 16:37:56 1   
    6   2018-09-06 16:38:14 1   
    7   2018-09-06 16:43:53 1
```

I want to store this data into mysql table "scheduler". I read the contents using file_get_contents() but how do I insert this contents into the scheduler table with columns sid,date,time and stat?

```
if(!empty($_FILES)) {
 $file = file_get_contents($_FILES["upload_cont_dat"]["tmp_name"], true);
 // store content in table
 }
```

Comment: With INSERT query ?

Comment: Yes using insert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a little script who read the file and parse for each line and get all data. After that I insert it in MySQL database.

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("exmple.dat", "r");
if ($handle) {
    $con = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_databasename);
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        // process the line read.
        $line_exp = explode(" ", $line);
        $sid = $line_exp[0];
        $date = $line_exp[3];
        $time = $line_exp[4];
        $stat = $line_exp[5];
        $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `scheduler` (`sid`, `date`, `time`, `stat`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $sid, $date, $time, $stat);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    $stmt->close();
    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // error opening the file.
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This helped immensely.

Comment: No problem, glad it helps